# How to graph trig functions on a TI-nspire CX CAS?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm completely lost here trying to graph a trig function on my TI-nspire CX CAS calculator.
I'm asked to graph:

t=time

t(θ) = 75/13 - 25/13cot(θ) + 25/6csc(θ),

Where 0≤t≤20 and 0º≤0≤90º.

I have searched the web and there are a few tutorials on how to do this, but they only explain how to graph the most basic trig functions. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: First rewrite your function in terms of the basic trig functions the calculator knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Recall that $\cot(\theta) = \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$ and $\csc(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$.  Can you take it from there?